# Installation problem with centOS 5.3 linux

Tags: linux

I have already installed one software (Elastix 1.5) on CentOS 5.3 in a system.

But now I want to install same software in different machine. But I am facing one problem to install same software in a different machine (which have CentOS 5.3 already). When I install it then I receive the following error -

**Transaction Check Error:
package kernel-xen-2.6.18-128.el5.i686 (which is newer than kernel-xen-2.6.18-92.1.22.el5.i686) is already installed**

Anybody know the reason of this problem.

Comment: I want to mentioned here that I am using same centOS version and software (which was successfully install), but in another machine when I install centOS 5.3 (same DVD used by previous) and software (same used by previous), error message appear. But in both cases, machine configuration are different. Can it be a problem?
If 'Yes', it means according to hardware configuration, linux kernel is changed. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Somebody has already installed at least part of XEN on the machine that already has Centos, and the installed version is NEWER than the one which comes along with Elastix 1.5. Either find a newer version of Elastix that will work with the xen-2.6.18-128.el5 or else you will have to downgrade the existing machine by removing XEN and reinstalling. Since this is part of the kernel it could be a painful process.

On the [Elastix website](http://www.elastix.org/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=137&Itemid=60), the latest version is 1.5.2. Is this what you are using?

I suspect that the installer asks you if XEN is already installed. If this is true, then you could try again and this time say "yes", however you will have two slightly different machines. An alternate route, and the one that I would use, is to manage XEN and the appliance completely separately. I would get both machines to have an up-to-date release of XEN, test that it is working, and then get the Elastix VMWare image and convert it to a XEN image.

[qemu-img](http://www.qemu.org/qemu-doc.html#SEC19) does a fine job at converting VMWare images.

Comment: First thanks to Michael and dyasny for your helpful suggestion. I would like you to inform that I have solved this problem. For solve it, first I uninstall XEN from my PC than install software again. And now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

looks like the installer requires a specific version of the kernel.
you should install the older kernel and remove the newer one, if your software requires it.